# PhoneGap + JqueryMobile on Xcode

Tags: xcode4, jquery-mobile, cordova

Attempting a beginner's tutorial.

I have the following in my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
<linkrel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

My result is just text, no Jquery mobile styling.

Comment: If you are creating a native application, I recommend not relying on external resources where you don't have to. By that I mean, host the jQuery and jQuery Mobile files just like you host the PhoneGap files, on the device. This way the app. will work without an internet connection and will not take as long to startup. Also jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 supports jQuery Core 1.6.4, not 1.7.1: http://www.jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your mobile css not applying?
That CSS Link is invalid. You are missing the hyphen (-) in the link:

Here's the correct URL: 
   http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css

Comment: +1, you can verify this by pasting the the URL you've used for your jQuery Mobile stylesheet.